# importing mx.graphics.codec.*

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am trying to import a FlashDevelop project into Flash Builder. I simply started an ActionScript project and dragged and dropped files & created packages as needed, selected "Set as Default Application" on the main file .as file and deleted the default application .as file.

But when I compile I get the following errors

```
1172: Definition mx.graphics.codec:JPEGEncoder could not be found.
        line 15 Flex Problem
1172: Definition mx.graphics.codec:PNGEncoder could not be found.   
                line 16 Flex Problem
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method JPGEncoder.
                line 175 Flex Problem
```

In my build path I have Flex 4.5.1 and for framework linkage I am doing "Merged into code". I see in [help for adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/codec/package-detail.html) that the classes are part of the core for Flex 4.5.1.

So not sure what I am doing wrong? I only want to compile a swf and I am pretty sure FlashDevelop was doing the same before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mx.graphics.* is under framework.swc not in mx.swc, the lib does not get added in an AS project. Thought I would just answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case there is anyone still seeking, copy the swc from Flex SDK:

```
flex_sdk\frameworks\libs
```